# How can I show MainActivity's layout in onCreate() method?

Tags: android

I just started studying android, and kind of puzzled with drawing layout on screen.
What I'm trying to do is,

1> show MainActivity's layout - which is designed in xml layout file

2> wait for 2 seconds, still showing MainActivity

3> Move on to next Activity

And with my recent code, it shows only white blank screen for 2 secs, and then next activity shows up.

This is my source code for MainActivity, at now.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent settingIntent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            //
        }
        settingIntent = new Intent(this,SettingActivity.class);
        startActivity(settingIntent);
    }
}
```

How can I make this work as my intention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use default method of `View`s - `postDelayd`

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent settingIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(settingIntent);
        }
    }, 2000);
```

write it after

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and remove `onStart`

Answer (score 2):

When you call sleep you're pausing the UI thread. Which isn't what you're after. Instead do this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            settingIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(settingIntent);
        }
    }, 2000);

}
```

**EDIT**

As Commonsware has rightly pointed out, this has the potential to introduce a memory leak. You should consider using the solution @yidavewu has posted.

Comment: Do not create an anonymous inner class instance of `Handler`; you may be introducing a memory leak. Since `postDelayed()` is also a method on `View`, it would be safer to use `findViewById(android.R.id.content).postDelayed(...)`.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are correct. I completely forgot that View has a postDelayed method.

Comment: I was not sure whether sleep() method pausing the UI thread, and how to solve the problem. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I know is onStart callback tells that acitivity is just about to be shown.
So it's not yet shown. The better choice is to put your code for showing new activity in onResume callback.

Comment: I also tried that way before calling in OnStart(), and it didn't work.